# MetaMask RPC error: Invalid transaction params

Tags: web3js, metamask

I'm getting this error when I try to do a transaction on MetaMask.

> MetaMask - RPC Error: Invalid transaction params: params specify an EIP-1559 transaction but the current network does not support EIP-1559 {code: -32602, message: 'Invalid transaction params: params specify an EIP-…but the current network does not support EIP-1559'}

I'm using the latest MetaMask version 10.8.1 and the net is Mumbai.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made some investigation and it was because of the RPC url I've used for mumbai testnet.

https://rpc.maticvigil.com/

Get my own RPC url here and it solved the problem.

Thank you.